# Keyboard Teleop settings

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I write a program in arduino.
i  want to do the same with ros-keyboard_teleop.
can sombody guide me ?any tutorial link.

```
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(24, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(25, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() 
{ 
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    char data = Serial.read();
    
    if(data == 'i')
    {
      digitalWrite(24, LOW);
      digitalWrite(25, HIGH);
     Serial.println("reverse");
    }
    else if(data == 'j')
    {
      digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(25, LOW);
      Serial.println("forward");
      
    }
   else
    {
      digitalWrite(24,LOW);
      digitalWrite(25,LOW);
     Serial.println("stop"); 
    }}}
```

i did a program. but i think there is a problem with

> else if (y = vel.linear.y - 1.0)
> can you check my code and tell me where is the problem?

```
   #include <ros.h>
    #include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
    float x;
    float y; 
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    void velCallback(  const geometry_msgs::Twist& vel)
    {
       if (x = vel.linear.x - 1.0) //Forward move.
          {
          digitalWrite(24, LOW);
          digitalWrite(23, HIGH);
          }
    else if (y = vel.linear.y - 1.0)   //Backward move
    {
          digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(23, LOW);
    }
    else 
    {
        digitalWrite(24, LOW);     //STOP
          digitalWrite(23, LOW);
    }
        }

ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Twist> sub("cmd_vel" , velCallback);

void setup() 
{
     nh.initNode();
     nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop() 
{
     nh.spinOnce();
     delay(10);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284773/keyboard-teleop-settings./) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-08**:
`teleop_twist_keyboard` publishes a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message type on the `/cmd_vel` topic. You should make your arduino subscribe to this. A few other projects that do this are https://sungjik.wordpress.com/tag/ros/ and https://answers.ros.org/question/258563/subscribe-cmd_vel-with-arduino/

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-03-08**:
can you please write how the code should be ? i checked the links.but still dont have idea how to do so.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-08**:
The code in https://answers.ros.org/question/258563/subscribe-cmd_vel-with-arduino/ is how most of the code should be. The only thing you need to add is the digitalWrite commands for your motors in velCallback.

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-03-09**:
i just updated my program.can you check the code ?i face the problem with y axis.

```
rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
```

is this the twist_keboard command

**Comment by [simchanu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28658/simchanu/) on 2018-03-09**:
Why do you use Y axis for a backward move ? Y axis is usually for lateral moves, and Z axis of `vel.angular` for turning.

Can you explain in the question how your robot moves ? (2 motorized wheels maybe) I think it would help people to understand your needs.

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-03-10**:
sorry im new to this.i dont know how the code supposed to be.what i want is if i press "i" it should execute first IF condition which is forward move.and if i press any other key whether it is j or k any, it goes backward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The conditionals in your velocity callback aren't meaningful c++:

```
if (x = vel.linear.x - 1.0) //Forward move.
{
      digitalWrite(24, LOW);
      digitalWrite(23, HIGH);
}
else if (y = vel.linear.y - 1.0)   //Backward move
{
      digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(23, LOW);
}
else 
{
      digitalWrite(24, LOW);     //STOP
      digitalWrite(23, LOW);
}
```

Since you use the single equals sign you're changing the value of x and y instead of checking it. Instead you should use the less-than and greater-than operators (and a little bit of wiggle room so you don't need to send exactly 0 to stop):

```
if (vel.linear.x > 0.1) //Forward move.
{
      digitalWrite(24, LOW);
      digitalWrite(23, HIGH);
}
else if (vel.linear.x < -0.1)   //Backward move
{
      digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(23, LOW);
}
else 
{
      digitalWrite(24, LOW);     //STOP
      digitalWrite(23, LOW);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-03-10**:
is there any other function than this `vel.linear.x`  what if i want to change the y or z axis ? keyword for that ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-10**:
Yes, the twist message also has y and z components, as well as x, y and z angular components. The full documentation is on the [geometry_msgs page](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs) on the ROS wiki.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-10**:
teleop_twist_keyboard is able to send x, y and z velocities and yaw (rotation about Z), but from your code it seems like your robot can only move forwards and backwards (+/- X) so I'm not sure that the other axes will be useful for you.